# You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered, useNavigate error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, use-effect

I have a problem with using navigate in one of my context's functions. I have a function called getCurrencyFromPath that is provided to my component via useContext. This function is called in useEffect, only on component's mount, to get a currency from query parameter (example path: /HistoricalRates?currency=USD). If someone would try to pass a currency (into query parameter) that is not valid for my app I'd like to navigate user to a default currency which is USD. So in my function I have an "if" check, if query parameter is ok, if not then navigate. So when user passes this wrong query parameter my page mounts and at once navigate should be called, but it's not and instead I get this error. If i call navigate directly in useEffect it works, there is no error, but as soon as i try to do the same logic with outsourcing this code to context function I get an error.

PS. I want to keep this logic in this context function, putting this directly in useEffect is not what I want to achieve (although it would solve the problem)

```
// component

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const { getCurrencyFromPath, currency, setCurrency } = React.useContext(HistoricalRatesContext);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getCurrencyFromPath();
  }, []);

  const onPickerValueChange = (currency: Currencies) => {
    navigate(`/HistoricalRates?currency=${currency}`);
    setCurrency(currency);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.chartHeader}>
      <PageHeader text={`USD historical rates`}></PageHeader>
      <CurrencyPicker className={classes.pickerAdditional} value={currency} 
       changeValue={onPickerValueChange} blockedCurrencies={[Currencies.PLN]} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;

// context

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

.
.
.

const navigate = useNavigate();

const getCurrencyFromPath = () => {
    let currency = query.get('currency') || '';

    if (!isValidCurrency(currency)) {
      currency = Currencies.USD;
      navigate(`/HistoricalRates?currency=${currency}`);
    }

    setCurrency(currency as Currencies);
  };
```

Comment: useNavigate() it is used inside a React Component ?

Comment: actuallty it's used both in context and in component. But this one  in component is used for another purpose, it doesn't have anything to do with getCurrencyFromPath. The one used by context is imported in context

Comment: Could u post the entire component when the error occurs pls

Comment: I updated the post, there is entire component there now :D

Answer (score 0):

This part should'nt be in the component of this route /HistoricalRates?currency=${currency}

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getCurrencyFromPath();
  }, []);
```

Comment: As i wrote in my question i know that removing this function and writing this logic directly in useEfeect solves my problem, but my question is what to do if i want to keep this logic in my context function and use it as it's used in my example? Can I do something to be able to use this function?